# Thymeleaf Form Request method 'POST' not supported, HTTP Error = Method Not Allowed, status=405

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am new into Thymeleaf and here I made a Form using Thymeleaf but running into this issue. 
I read many many articles but didn't find any solution.

Here's my Controller Class ->

```
@Controller

public class SavingUser{

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;


@PostMapping("/registerUser")
public ModelAndView user(@ModelAttribute Customer customer, ModelMap model){
    System.out.println("User in registration page..");
    userRepository.save(customer);
    model.addAttribute("saveUser", customer);
    return new ModelAndView("index");
 }
}
```

And here's my HTML Form -

```
  <div id="form">
    <form action="registerUser" th:action="@{/registerUser}"  th:object="${saveUser}" method="POST">
        <br />
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
        <label for="name">Your Name:</label><br />
        <input type="text" th:field="*{name}"  placeholder="" /><br />

        <label for="suburb">Your Suburb</label><br />
        <input type="text"  th:field="*{suburb}"  placeholder="" /><br />

        
            <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"  />
            <br /><br />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I tried not put **action=""**, still it didn't work.
Any solution, thanks in advance.

Comment: `POST` and `GET` with the same context path `/registerUser` ? Think it wont work.

Comment: Oops, this one i added lastly but even I delete the whole Get request, still showing the  same error.

Comment: Did you refer this? https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/ . I am doubting you have issue in how you are rendering your HTML form. Can you show the controller code for rendering this form?

Comment: There it's on top of this page. Do you think  SQL database's error will cause such an error ?